# Angular JS ng-include javascript not working partial onload

Tags: angularjs

**Issue:**

I have a ng-include directive pointing to an html partial that has a pre element inside. I have some javascript code that targets any pre element either on the parent page or the child partial page. I am able to target any pre elements on the target page but not able to target pre elements or any other elements for that matter on the child partial page.

**My Tests**
I have observed that when I turn my chrome extension to clear the cache I am able to reference the pre element but when I turn it off I cannot reference the pre element.

I have tried to use `.run( function () {$templateCache.removeAll() } )` but that didn't work.

I also tried to use `$window.load` and the `onload` attribute on the ng-include div element and that also didn't work.

**The Setup**

**index.html**

```
<div data-ng-include("'partial.html'")></div>
```

**partial.html**

```
<pre><p>This is a pre element</p></pre>
```

**app.js**

```
var pre = document.getElementsByTagName( "pre" );

                for( var i = 0; i < pre.length; i++ ){
                    console.log( pre[i].innerHTML );
                }
```

You can also see the example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l4H93cbWsgsti1Lkd9iZ?p=linter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be processed before the `ng-include` gives the HTML to parse.

You need to trigger the function only when the HTML is already loaded.

Also, change some declarations on your code:

```
<div data-ng-include("'partial.html'")></div>

// to

<div data-ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>
```

Add the `onload` attribute with the call to your function scoped on your controller:

```
<div data-ng-include="'partial.html'" onload="onLoad()"></div>
```

Actually, there's a concern about this approach: you want to do `DOM` manipulation inside a controller. This is not a conventional way to deal with it on Angular. You need to setup a directive for it and do your handling/parsing of DOM there.

Also, you don't need to apply a broad call like that to manage DOM modifications. You can setup a directive for the `<pre>` elements that you want and let them do the job.